# MVC with Angular

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am a bit confused.

As a contractor I look out for what technologies I should learn to make me more marketable.

I am a MVC Web Developer.

I have noticed Angular.js seems to be listed as a wanted skill in job adverts alongside MVC skills.

Looking at Angular it does not seem difficult to learn.

However, there does seem to be a clash with Angular's Ajax calls and MVC's web api.

So, can these 2 technologies co-exist in the same web app?  Is the best way is to drop Razor and Angular's AJAX calls and use the Web API?

I have been searching on this for some time and still cannot get a definitive answer..

Thanks

Comment: How does Angular 'conflict' with Web API calls? If anything the SPA (if used as such) design of Angular conflicts with MVC views and server postbacks.

Comment: @user2864740 Hi, thanks for your comment. Normally, I would use a JSON call to get my data from my API Controller. Does not Angular.js offer its own AJAX call to get JSON data too?

Comment: Angular consumes JSON. MVC Web API exposes JSON. Where is the conflict?

Comment: Hi, Thanks again for your comments.  The data format is the same of course. But, Angular would use something like this:  $http.get("http://a uri") and MVC would use something like this:    $.getJSON(uri)

Comment: {thank you for trying to educate me BTW :) }

Comment: `$http.get` is a JavaScript call in Angular to make an XHR request. `$.getJSON` is a JavaScript call in jQuery to make an XHR request. Neither of these pertain to MVC Web API (that runs on the server).

Comment: That is a good point lol.  OK, I am happy.  Thanks

Comment: I have never heard of *MVC Web Developer* profession.

Comment: Really? Check out job serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of an Angular app as disconnected from your backend as an Android or iOS app would be. If you're doing it right your entire Angular app is static, with no server side templating (a nice side effect of this is that your Angular app can be pushed to a CDN). If you have a traditional server side templating background it can be very tempting to do "double templating" (server side and client side templating) in your Angular app. Don't do it. Your web server exposes an web services and that's it. Your Angular app uses those web services.

Comment: Hi, I do like the disconnected approach to the client-side.  I have no issue dropping the Razor stuff and instead use Static input.  Should I continue to use JSON calls calling my APIController or use the AJAX calls of Angular instead?

Comment: Typically your server exposes a REST services that serve JSON. You don't have to do it this way but it's by far the most common. When getting starting with Angular you'd try [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). I moved to [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) and haven't looked back.

Comment: Hi, thanks for those links.  I shall read them now.  With the Restangular it now begets what one to use.  KnockOut.js, Angular.js (which I heard was going to be re-written completely) and/or Restangular. So difficult - for me - to focus on what best to learn :)

Comment: Restangular is used within Angular - it is used instead of $http or $resource. And yes, Angular 2.0 is coming. Take a serious look at Angular 2 before starting your project. I wouldn't go with Knockout in 2015 personally. Right now the big three to me are Angular, Ember, and React.

Comment: Thanks again. Any idea when it will be released?